# Subset a vector with different criteria for different parts of the vector

Tags: r

Given a vector `sub`, I would like to subset the vector to remove any of the first `bp` elements that are no smaller than some threshold `x` and to remove any of the remaining elements that are no larger than some threshold `y`. Example data for this question might look like:

```
sub <- c(0.05588, 0.05588, 0.05588, 0.05588, 0.05588, 0.05588, 0.05588, 
  0.05588, 0.0625856, 0.0625856, 0.0625856, 0.0625856, 0.0625856, 
  0.0692912, 0.0692912, 0.0692912, 0.0692912, 0.0692912, 0.0692912, 
  0.0692912)
bp <- 10
x <- 0.06
y <- 0.07
```

I have tried the following code for the first half of the dataset:

```
sub[sub>=x][1:bp] <- NA
new <- na.omit(sub)
```

and this for the second half:

```
new[new<=y][bp:length(new)] <- NA
new2 <- na.omit(new)
```

This is a lengthy process and in the latter piece of code `[bp:length(new)]` never works properly.

Comment: What is the end goal for splitting the data? Do you wish to perform calculations on each subset of the data? Do you want a list of `data.frame` objects that will be used for various analyses? Would you benefit from creating a categorical variable for your different subsets?

Comment: The end goal would be to re combine the dataset with the threshold data removed. This is a tiny piece of the data which is time series. bp is the breakpoint of the data and so the threshold criteria differ each side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the question, you want to remove all elements above some threshold `x` for the first `bp` elements of your data and remove all elements below some threshold `y` for the remaining elements.

Let's consider this with a complete set of problem data:

```
set.seed(144)
(sub <- rnorm(10))
#  [1] -1.6505562  0.6028106 -0.4738839 -1.7976130 -1.4211210  0.1588875  0.1297662 -1.2561688
#  [9]  0.1476671  0.9791739
bp <- 5
x <- 0
y <- 0.13
```

Now we can perform the operation in a 1-liner in base R, removing the subset of the first 5 elements above 0 and the subset of the remaining elements below 0.13:

```
sub[!c(head(sub >= x, bp), tail(sub <= y, -bp))]
# [1] -1.6505562 -0.4738839 -1.7976130 -1.4211210  0.1588875  0.1476671  0.9791739
```

In this code, `head(sub >= x, bp)` returns the indicator for whether each of the first `bp` elements is at least `x` or greater, and then `tail(sub <= y, -bp)` returns the indicator for whether each of the remaining elements (`-bp` means "all but the first `bp`") is `y` or smaller. We then combine those two vectors of indicators and use them to remove any element of `sub` that has its indicator set to `TRUE`.

If you just wanted the indicator for whether each element should be removed from the vector, you can get that with:

```
c(head(sub >= x, bp), tail(sub <= y, -bp))
#  [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```